# Stale element Exception in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I tried to automate a scenario, where the condition is that I have to select all the drop down options and I have to click that options one by one. I tried with the code but it clicks only the first option,.And showing error as stale Element is not clickable.
Please help.

Comment: You should make sure the page is loaded and all the request are done and after that you can search for your element.

Comment: are you using POM? If yes, I can suggest something.

Comment: Yes ,please tell me

Comment: please, give your html portion

Answer (score 0):

`StaleElementException` occurs if I find an element, the DOM gets updated then I try to interact with the element.

So how do I handle it? use the following click method trying to click element multiple times:

```
public boolean retryingFindClick(By by) {
        boolean result = false;
        int attempts = 0;
        while(attempts < 2) {
            try {
                driver.findElement(by).click();
                result = true;
                break;
            } catch(StaleElementException e) {
            }
            attempts++;
        }
        return result;
}
```

Taken this excelent solution from [here](http://darrellgrainger.blogspot.com/2012/06/staleelementexception.html).

Answer (score 0):

When you are selecting an option from dropdown, your DOM are getting updated too. So, you need to update your object too. See the example code  snippet:

```
    Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("your dropdown's locator"))); // you may use any locator of your choice
    List<WebElement> options = select.getOptions();

    for(WebElement option : options){
            select.selectByVisibleText(option.getText());

            //re-assign your select object since your page has been reloaded after selecting an option 
            select =   new Select(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("your dropdown's locator")));
     }
```